# Python matplotlib - setting x-axis scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have this graph displaying the following:

```
plt.plot(valueX, scoreList)
plt.xlabel("Score number") # Text for X-Axis
plt.ylabel("Score") # Text for Y-Axis
plt.title("Scores for the topic "+progressDisplay.topicName)
plt.show()
```

valueX = [1, 2, 3, 4] and
scoreList = [5, 0, 0, 2]

I want the scale to go up in 1's, no matter what values are in 'scoreList'. Currently get my x-axis going up in .5 instead of 1s.

How do I set it so it goes up only in 1?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just set the xticks yourself.

```
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4])
```

or

```
plt.xticks(valueX)
```

Since the range functions happens to work with integers you could use that instead:

```
plt.xticks(range(1, 5))
```

Or be even more dynamic and calculate it from the data:

```
plt.xticks(range(min(valueX), max(valueX)+1))
```

Answer (score 17):

Below is my favorite way to set the scale of axes:

```
plt.xlim(-0.02, 0.05)
plt.ylim(-0.04, 0.04)
```

Answer (score 8):

Hey it looks like you need to set the x axis scale.

Try

```
matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale(1, 'linear')
```

[Here's the documentation for that function](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale)

Comment: This is incorrect in matplotlib 3. It should read `plt.gca().set_xscale('linear')`. Otherwise you'll get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Axes'` from writing `plt.axes.Axes` and `TypeError: set_xscale() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` from writing `set_xscale(1, 'linear')`.